# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 - Can't perform single logout

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

Whenever I perform logout in one of my service providers I always get the same error message:

Not a valid SAML 2.0 Request Message!
The message was not recognized by the SAML 2.0 SSO Provider. Please check the logs for more details.

Let's take salesforce for example... I have tried configuring it with https://myidpdomain:9443/samlsso and https://myidpdomain:9443/samlsso?wa=wsignout1.0 in the "Identity Provider Logout URL" setting.

The same with zendesk...

To both these service providers I have enabled the single logout checkbox in the SAML Inbound Authentication configuration.

The single sign on works fine.

Comment: In the system logs, I see nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SAML2 SSO Web browser or Passive STS ?  In SAML2 SSO web browser profile,  you can not send `wa=wsignout1.0` for logout.  It is not valid.  Therefore above error has been generated. `wa=wsignout1.0` is used in Passive STS profile not in SAML2 SSO. If you are using `/samlsso` end point in WSO2IS, It means that your are using SAML2 SSO.  Therefore, you must send a proper logout request to the `/samlsso` end point. If you need to get more idea about SSO logout with SAML2 SSO, Please go through [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/).

Comment: but it's not me sending the logout request but salesforce.. How do I configure salesforce to send a proper SAML2 SSO logout request ?